# Geometry Nodes : get a differet random value for each mesh after subdivide

Tags: geometry-nodes, random

I'm on Blender 3.6. I've made a geometry node to build a building from a plane, I want to build one to build a block, I subdivide a bigger plane and apply my geometry node for building (BatMain on the picture). It works (i've my buildigs) but i can't randomize the number of floors. I try everything but nothing works.

[image]
[image]

I've ever try to replace Value by Position or ID.

Comment: how shall we help you? we have no idea what your node group does...

Comment: There are quite a few ways of achieving  this.. which one would depend on your existing method. As @Chris says, for an answer that suits you, you would have to show us how you've got as far as you have. A plain-language description of your strategy, and a shared .blend on https://blend-exchange.com/ would really help folks to help you.

Comment: My file is to big for blend exchange....

Comment: I don't know how to explain in a better way (excuse my english)...
 - I have a geometry node (call BatMain), who, applied on a plane.... build a building with a number of floor dependending  on a parameter (NbFloor on the picture)...its work fine.
 - I try to build a "Block" (neighborhood?)  node for create many buildings of different height (floor numbers) on a plane.
 - I subdivide the plane (by 2, so ti's make 16 plane) ...
 - i apply my BatMain node (for bulding)... it's work, it's create my 16 buildings (image2)
 - i want to randomize the height (NbFloors)....  I cant....

Comment: Someone said me on another forum thats because the random value output is a square and the NbFloors Value input is circle, either the both are integer it cant work....